# ArrayOutOfBound Exception arising and crashing the app

Tags: java, android

I am making a simple calculator application in Android, but I am facing some error, when I press the percent button the app crashes and give me the following error. Basically what I am going to do is, if any of the symbols appears on the last index of the string, the `EditText` value should be decremented by 1 and the new value will be assigned. It work correct when I press any other button before pressing the percent button. But if I press the percent button first then other buttons the app crashes. That's basically the problem. To avoid placing the symbols first I have written the last else block, which simply shows a message in a `Toast`, but now it crashes.

**Below is the Java Code**

```
public void calculate(View v){

    String t;
    ma_res_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ma_res_txt);
    String[] signs ={"%","÷","+","×","π","!","√",".","×^"};
    int length = ma_res_txt.getText().length();
    String txt = ma_res_txt.getText().toString();

    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.cal_btn_clear:{
            ma_res_txt.setText("");
            break;
        }

        case R.id.cal_btn_del:{
            try {
                if(length>0){
                    ma_res_txt.setText(txt.substring(0, length - 1));
                } else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No more characters left",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No more characters left",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        }

        case R.id.cal_btn_percent:{
            t = "%";
            String s = txt.substring(length-1,length);

            if(length>0) {
                if(s.equals("%") || s.equals("÷") || s.equals("+") || s.equals("×") || s.equals("^") ){
                    ma_res_txt.setText(txt.substring(0, length - 1));
                    ma_res_txt.append(t);
                }
                else {
                    ma_res_txt.append(t);
                }
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Syntax Error !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the error I am getting. Even when surrounding with try catch blocks, the app still crashes.**

```
08-02 20:17:16.105 26307-26307/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                         Process: com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator, PID: 26307
                                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                             at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5044)
                                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
                                                                                             at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103)
                                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653)
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                             at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5039)
                                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205) 
                                                                                             at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103) 
                                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653) 
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410) 
                                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1
                                                                                             at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1926)
                                                                                             at com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator.MainActivity.calculate(MainActivity.java:87)
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                             at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5039) 
                                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205) 
                                                                                             at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103) 
                                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653) 
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

**XML**

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="211dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/ma_res_txt"
        android:paddingLeft="17dp"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:focusedByDefault="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"


        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/btn_ctrl_linear"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ma_res_txt"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Voice Control"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/show_voice_ctrl"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue_white"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Camera Control"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/show_cam_ctrl"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue_white"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

  <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/btn_ctrl_linear"
      >
      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:weightSum="1"
          >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/cal_btn_set1"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="C"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:textColor="#027fcc"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_clear"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="%"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:textColor="#027fcc"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_percent"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="÷"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textColor="#027fcc"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_divide"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="del"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#027fcc"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_del"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/cal_btn_set2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cal_btn_set1"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="7"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_7"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="8"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_8"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="9"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_9"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#027fcc"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_plus"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/cal_btn_set3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cal_btn_set2"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_4"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_5"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_6"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="×"
            android:typeface="monospace"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:textColor="#027fcc"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_mult"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/cal_btn_set4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cal_btn_set3"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_1"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_2"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_3"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="π"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="#027fcc"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_pi"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/cal_btn_set5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cal_btn_set4"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="√"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#027fcc"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_root"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_0"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="."
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:textColor="#027fcc"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_dot"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="×^"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#027fcc"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_power"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/cal_btn_set6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cal_btn_set5"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="sin"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textColor="#027fcc"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_sin"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="cos"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textColor="#027fcc"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_cos"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="tan"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textColor="#027fcc"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_tan"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:text="!"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#027fcc"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/cal_btn_ptrl"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:id="@+id/cal_btn_set7"
              android:layout_below="@+id/cal_btn_set6"
              >
              <Button
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="65dp"
                  android:text="sin(-1)"
                  android:textAllCaps="false"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
                  android:textSize="12dp"
                  android:textColor="#027fcc"
                  android:textStyle="italic"
                  android:layout_margin="1dp"
                  android:id="@+id/cal_btn_sinIn"
                  android:onClick="calculate"
                  />
              <Button
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="65dp"
                  android:text="cos(-1)"
                  android:textAllCaps="false"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
                  android:textSize="12dp"
                  android:textColor="#027fcc"
                  android:textStyle="italic"
                  android:layout_margin="1dp"
                  android:id="@+id/cal_btn_cosIn"
                  android:onClick="calculate"
                  />
              <Button
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="65dp"
                  android:text="tan(-1)"
                  android:textAllCaps="false"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_ripple_blue"
                  android:textSize="12dp"
                  android:textStyle="italic"
                  android:textColor="#027fcc"
                  android:layout_margin="1dp"
                  android:id="@+id/cal_btn_tanIn"
                  android:onClick="calculate"
                  />
              <Button
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="65dp"
                  android:text="="
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="@drawable/custome_btn_ripple_grey"
                  android:textSize="30dp"
                  android:textColor="#fff"
                  android:layout_margin="1dp"
                  android:id="@+id/cal_btn_equal"
                  android:onClick="calculate"
                  />

          </LinearLayout>




      </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You did not check the length of `txt` before calling substring on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `String s = txt.substring(length-1,length);` you have not checked if your length > 0 and your txt is empty if you press the % button first and hence your index is out of bound

Comment: Great, that was the problem, Thanks mate !

Comment: Great happy to help. Please accept the answer :)